# Unable to find connection 'SchoolDBConnectionString (Settings)1'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, dataset

Please I am getting an error in Visual Studio 2013 on a VB.NET project I am working on.The error says

**Unable to find connection 'SchoolDBConnectionString (Settings)1' for object 'Settings'. The connection string could not be found in application settings, or the data provider associated with the connection string could not be loaded.** This happens when I try to open my **Dataset.**

I tried searching the internet for a solution and found out that the **Dataset.xsd** file may contain more than one connection string and that deleting the extra connection strings may solve the problem. I tried it but when ever I edit the **Dataset.xsd** file, the **Dataset.designer.vb** file disappears causing over 100 errors. Please I want your support. Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest that you delete your `DataSet` and also any connection strings from your settings, then create a new `DataSet`.

Comment: ok...I tried and its working now. thanks @jmcilhinney